# How to have a collection in another collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a problem..In my program I need to have a collection of `User`, another collection in this with all projects where the user participted and the number of `hours` he worked in each project.

I have 3 tables for this problem:

- `users` table, prety simple with.
- `projects` table.
- `time_entries`, with `user_id` and `project_id`.

A `project` can have many `time_entries` and the `user` to.

I have test that but it's not working:

```php
$users = User::join('time_entries', 'users.id', '=', 'time_entries.user_id')
  ->whereBetween('spent_on', [($request->input('debut')), ($request->input('fin'))])
  ->join('projects', 'time_entries.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
  ->selectRaw('user_id , project_id, sum(hours) as sum')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a [Many-to-Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between your `User`/`Project` models using [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent):

```
/** User.php */

public function projects()
{
    return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'time_entries')
            ->withPivot('hours');
}
```

--

```
/** Project.php */

public function users()
{
    return $this
            ->belongsToMany(User::class, 'time_entries')
            ->withPivot('hours');
}
```

Then just access the relationship:

```
/** UserController.php */

public function myFunction()
{
    $users = User::with('projects')->get();
    // this $users collection will have another collection inside (projects).


    $projects_of_first_user = $users->first()->projects;
}
```

Comment: ``` $users = User::with('projects')->get();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            var_dump ($user->projects->name);
        } ``` with that I can't have the name of projects. I'm very bad with eloquent aha

Comment: yes you could: `$user->-first()->projects->first()->name;`